# UITableView disappeared on reload iOS 7

Tags: uitableview, ios7

I have an app that is working on iOS5, 5.1 and 6. Now with the new iOS7 I was checking that it works and the only problem is with my `UITableView`.

I have two tables that when you select a row it completes a segue to another view. You can then modify the data and when you click the "Ok" button, you return to the previous view (the table's view), and I have a `reloadData` to update the information. But when I click to another row, the table disappears. It only happens in iOS7 and I don't know the problem, it happens on the simulator and iPad too.

Thanks.

Comment: I have a similar problem.  My app has 2 ways of looking at table data. I allow the user to toggle between them.  Works great is ios 5 and 6. IOS 7 seems to have tried to optimize the reloaddata, and it does not reload all the data.  Some rows contain values reused from other rows.  I'm thinking about not reusing my cells.

Comment: We have found a solution, our problem was with the View navigation. When we do a "popToViewController", it erase the UITableView reference and the data disappeared.